# I have a for loop trying to plot multiple graphs, but they are plotted over each other, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code, which is supposed to return multiple graphs, for some reason I cannot figure out (never had this problem). I get multiple graphs, but as it iterates through the loop the graph after the first contains all previous ones.

```
for x in np.arange(0,3):
    t1= table.iloc[x,2]
    t2= table.iloc[44,2]
    dts = np.arange(-0.02,0.02,0.0001)
    cc = np.zeros(len(dts))
    for i,dt in enumerate(dts):
        n1,v=np.histogram(t1,899*100)
        n2,v=np.histogram(t2-dt,bins=v)
        cc[i] = np.corrcoef(n1,n2)[0,1]
    plt.plot(dts,cc)
    #plt.title(str(table[table['ClusterNames']==test1.iloc[x,0]].iloc[0,0])+'_'+str(table[table['ClusterNames']==test1.iloc[x,1]].iloc[0,0]))
    filename='step'+str(x).zfill(6)+'.png'
    plt.savefig(filename, form='png', dpi = 96, transparent = True)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. To clear the plot after saves, you could add `plt.clf()` to the end of your loop. To plot everything on one page, you can use `plt.subplot2grid` OR `plt.subplots`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want each figure in a different window, you should add `plt.figure()` before `plt.plot()`

Comment: Thank you very much!